# Override UINavigationController's UINavigationTransitionView clipToBounds

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating a custom segue to do custom animation (page curl) when pushing/popping a UINavigationController. The animation works fine except for the fact that it's clipped to the boundaries of the UINavigationController. I've checked all the related views to make sure `clipToBounds` are set to `NO`, no luck.

Then I looked at the view hierarchy of UINavigationController itself and found the culprit, a subview of type UINavigationTransitionView. Setting this view's clipToBound to NO does the trick. However, since the view is most likely private and undocumented, it feels hacky/brittle. Is there any other way to accomplish this?